# How to force redraw of android UI?

Tags: android, view, adapter

When we initialise adapters, we have method getView. As I understand, each time it is called, It redraws the UI. Is there other ways to redraw UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `adapater.notifyDataSetChanged()`

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Answer (score 1):

notifyDataSetChanged() will redraw all views in your adapter.

A neat trick if you want to redraw only one view from your adapter is to call getView manually for it if its position is visible - i.e. when you have multiple rows and each one updates independently from the others. In such a scenario, it would be a waste to call notifyDataSetChanged every time a single row gets updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `notifyDataSetChanged()` method for adapter.

Which is called as `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Which informs Adapter that background task is completed and now the data set is changed.

you can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)